# Webpack + React + Sass + Bootstrap = autocompletion not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, sass, webpack

I have problem with setting environment for my project. I would like to use WebStorm to develop my React site.

My project is based on Webpack, React, Sass and Bootstrap and I have problem with setting Sass autocompletion in my `*.js` files.

Actually I have working project, but I would like to allow `WebStorm to autocomplete Bootstrap classes.

I have installed the `bootstrap-loader` library together with `bootstrap` and `bootstrap-sass` and it allows me to use Bootstrap in my project. But this solution does not provide autocompletion sources for `WebStorm`.

I tried to include `bootstrap` libraries in my `index.scss` but it does not work.

Is there a way to show to WebStorm's autocompletion sources (because Bootstrap libraries are included by Webpack automatically and it does not know about it)? Or maybe I have done it wrong.

Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Please give a [mcve].

Comment: It's hard to prepare example, because my code is compilling and working fine. The only problem is that my environment (WebStorm) does not see Sass sources and cannot show them in autocomplete feature.
I have included all references and libraries i used in my project. The only way is to prepare a sample project on GitHub to show the problem. Do you need it?